# Java turning two arrays into one two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays with the same length in my program, courseGrades and courseCredits, that look something like this:

```
courseGrades[] = {A, A, B, A, C, A};
courseCredits[] = {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1};
```

I want to combine them into one two-dimensional array that would display like this:

```
A    A    B    A    C    A
1    2    1    3    2    1
```

How would I do this in Java? 
Additionally, how would you refer to each element in this array?
Sorry for the very simple question, I'm still a beginner at java.

Comment: I think you have to copy the array elements.  It might be possible to just assign the references, but I'd have to test it (you could too).

Comment: If you cast `courseGrades` and `courseCredits` to `Object[]`, then you can have your expected result as `Object[][] results = new Object[][2](); result[0] = courseGrades; result[1] = courseCredits;` and no memory copying will happen. Still, if you want to remember that one array holds `int`s and the other - `String`s, then you're out of luck. What you actually need to do is to create `Course` class that will keep `grade` and `credit` - then you make an array of `Course`s instead of two arrays for its parts.

Comment: PS. code snippet was not checked - grammar may be wrong, because I don't usually use arrays and more often work with lists and other collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Pair` class, like this:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {
    public K key;
    public V value;

    public Pair() {}

    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And then you create an array of `Pairs`. I have not worked in Java for a while, so I might have committed some typos here, but this is the idea:

```
Pair<char, int> result[] = new Pair<char, int>[keys.length];

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    result[i] = new Pair<char, int>(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to combine an array of strings with an array of `int`s into a 2D array.

In Java, 2D arrays can only store one kind of thing, so there is no type-safe way to do this. A type-unsafe way to do this would be to store them in an `Object[][]`:

```
String[] grades = {"A", "B", "C"};
Integer[] credits = {1, 2, 3};
Object[][] gradesAndCredits = { grades, credits };
for (int i = 0; i < gradesAndCredits.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < gradesAndCredits[i].length ; j++) {
        System.out.print(gradesAndCredits[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you want the items in the subarrays as `String`s and `Integer`s, you'd need to cast them, which is type-unsafe.

Alternatively, you can store these pairs in a `HashMap` if it makes sense for one of them to act as the "key" and the other the "value".

```
String[] grades = {"A", "B", "C"};
Integer[] credits = {1, 2, 3};
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < grades.length ; i++) {
    map.put(grades[i], credits[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can assign the references, but only if the array is not an array of primitives, like `int` or `double`

```
String[] letterGrades = { "A", "B", "C" };
int[] numberGrades = { 1, 2, 3 };
Object[][] combined = new Object[2][];
combined[0] = letterGrades;
combined[1] = numberGrades;  // error here
```

So in this case instead of `int[]` you'd have to use `Integer[]` or copy the elements to a new array.