# Apache Simple Linear Regression In Java using Math Library

Tags: java, linear-regression

I am quite a newbie in using the apache library for a simple linear regress.
Task: I want to calculate the slope.

I have two linear lists, i.e., x-list and y-list. Y list values are the series of number. I am populating x-list by fetching value from a hashmap.

However, when I am trying to apply simpleRegression utility of apache library I am facing below difficulty:

Here is my code:

```
while(i< segmentI)
                {
                    xList.add(Double.parseDouble(timeStamp.get(i)));
                    yList.add(Double.parseDouble("1"));
                    i++;
                }
                for(int m=0; i< segmentI; i++)
                {
                        simpleRegression.addData(new double[][]{
                                {xList.get(m),yList.get(m)}
                        });

                }
```

Doubt: Is there any way can I create new double[][] before passing it to simpleRegression.
Also, new double[][]-it is a matrix then what would be the value of [0,1], [0,2]... so on because we don't have anything like that in single ArrayList.

Anything in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: The Apache foundation supports lots of different projects. Which Apache library are you using? -- *Y-list always contains a value of 1* -- Then the output of the linear regression will have slope 0 and intercept 1

Comment: I mean to say for y, i.e., y2-y1 will always be 1.
For the library I am using: commons-math3

Comment: Create a 2-dimension array from two 1-D arrays: [Java turning two arrays into one two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233799/java-turning-two-arrays-into-one-two-dimensional-array). Then you can use the examples provided in the documentation for [simple regression](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way can I create new double[][] before passing it to simpleRegression

Yes. For example

```
            double[][] data = new data[1][2];

            for(int m=0; m < segmentI; m++)
            {
                    data[0][0] = xList.get(m);
                    data[0][1] = yList.get(m);
                    simpleRegression.addData(data);
            }
```

You know there's also [a method that you can call without an array](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html)?

```
simpleRegression.addData(xList.get(m), yList.get(m));
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked with below changes:
double[][] pqr={ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(yList.toArray(new Double[0])),ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(xList.toArray(new Double[0]))};
simpleRegression.addData(pqr);